# Compress JP2 (JPEG2000) image with a high compression level

Tags: c#, .net, http-compression, image-conversion, jpeg2000

After reading Image from database, I need to convert that Image to JP2 (JPEG2000)

Update:

I used FreeImage to convert the image to JP2

```
   // Load bitmap           
   FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadEx(imageName);
// Check success
if (dib.IsNull)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not load Sample.jpg", "Error");
    return;
}    

// Convert Bitmap to JPEG2000 and save it on the hard disk
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JP2, dib, "Image.jp2", FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.DEFAULT);

// Unload source bitmap
FreeImage.UnloadEx(ref dib);
```

Now, I need to compress this image with a high compression level!

Comment: This link will probably give you a hint:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590471/jpeg-2000-support-in-c-net

Comment: What have you tried? What error did you get? Where is your problem (reading from the database or converting the image?

Comment: @Sascha I don't know how to convert the Image to JP2, I downloaded FreeImage to try it ... the problem is not to read from database

Comment: @ruckuus thanks... now, i need to compress that image with a high compression level

Comment: If you found the answer, please, consider answering your own question instead of editing it with the solution.

Comment: I tried to .. but i couldn't

Comment: I think i didn't tick on "Allow answer your question" when i created this question .. Is there any way to redo this or give me the ability to answer my question?

Comment: Sorry, my browser was blocking the java script for asking the confirmation msg .. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I Found The Answer***

```
   // Load bitmap           
   FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadEx(imageName);
    //
    Check success
    if (dib.IsNull)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load Sample.jpg", "Error");
        return;
    }    

    // Convert Bitmap to JPEG2000 and save it on the hard disk
    FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JP2, dib, "Image.jp2", FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.EXR_PXR24 | FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.EXR_LC);

    // Unload source bitmap
    FreeImage.UnloadEx(ref dib);
```

Comment: The EXR_ values are for the EXR file format. What you have written just happens to be interpreted as a 80:1 rate

Answer (score 0):

The flags for the JP2 (and J2K) formats is interpreted simply as a reduction factor. This is from the PluginJP2.cpp source

```
// if no rate entered, apply a 16:1 rate by default
if(flags == JP2_DEFAULT) {
    parameters.tcp_rates[0] = (float)16;
} else {
    // for now, the flags parameter is only used to specify the rate
    parameters.tcp_rates[0] = (float)(flags & 0x3FF);
}
```

So you can actually specify a reduction rate of up to 1023:1:

```
// Load bitmap           
FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadEx(imageName);
// Check success
if (dib.IsNull)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not load Sample.jpg", "Error");
    return;
}    

// Convert Bitmap to JPEG2000 and save it on the hard disk
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JP2, dib, "Image.jp2", (FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS)1023);

// Unload source bitmap
FreeImage.UnloadEx(ref dib);
```

This will give you a very small very low quality file.