# How to display JPEG2000 image (*.jp2) in picturebox

Tags: c#

Like this title, I want to display a JPEG2000 image file into picturebox but this file is not like a resource file, so I cannot display it. Please suggest me how to display it in picturebox?

Comment: take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590471/jpeg-2000-support-in-c-net

Comment: I seen. But there is no way to display it without third-party? Can you explain for me the step to show a JPEG2000 image? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG2000 is a totally different codec and there's no decoder for it available in Windows. You need to use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library

Of course you can also write one yourself, but writing any multimedia format is no easy feat and takes scientists years of research. It's not a smart decision to write your own decoder since it may take several years before you can use it, especially in your case when you don't even have a good enough background for developing it. Don't reinvent the wheel

It makes even less sense when your product is distributed commercially since there are a wider range of choices in libraries in that case, both free and proprietary. It's far cheaper to buy one and there's absolutely zero point wasting time and money on codec development

Comment: Writing your own jp2 decoder would be quite a task, not really practice. I suggest openjpeg

Comment: Yes, jp2 is much more complicated than the many year-old JPEG

Comment: @luu vinh phuc: I want to write new library, but I don't know how to start. maybe, I will consider about third-party libary. It is not good, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Free Image DLL](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html) from here

It's free and very easy to use.

Comment: I say that I don't want and cannot use third-party library because their licence and my product is commecial. if there is no way, please tell me how I can write new library to read and show jp2 file?

Comment: @TuyểnĐỗ: Well that's a silly decision.  I highly doubt you are going to write your own jp2 codec.  The fact that you would say something like *"please tell me how I can write new library to read and show jp2 file?"* tells me you're probably not ready to take such a task on.

Comment: I don't understand all your mean but also you want to say  that I make a silly decision. Nothing. If I really want to create a separate library to read and display JPEG2000, can you tell me how I can do it. or suggest me something I can use in commercial product?