# Pdf Downsizing with with Jpeg2000 compression medium quality

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrobat

Can some one help me there. I was planning to downsize a pdf just like what im doing in acrobat. But this time I want to do in c#. Is there any idea for this or is this possible?

Downsample image from 600DPI to 300PI
Compression is JPEG200 for colored images in pdf
Compresson is CCITT Group 4 for black and white images in pdf

Comment: iTextSharp will not apply lossy (destructive) compression to your images, that's left up to you. However, you can use [iTextSharp to extract your images](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8751517/231316) and then use another [third-party library to re-compress those images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590471/231316)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have just an image in the PDF file. If it es a complex file then search for a framework to do it.

When you have the image then it is realy simple:

- create a System.Drawing.Image object
- then use Image.Save with (Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms142148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- reopen the stream as an Image or use the save method with FileName instead of Stream