# How to generate thumbnail from .eps and .ai files in .NET?

Tags: .net, image, thumbnails, eps

A potential client is asking me if I can generate a thumbnail image from .eps and .ai files. The standard .NET Image class is not able to do this, so I suppose I need a 3rd party API, but I am not sure what is the best approach. Any ideas?

Roger

[Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some 3rd party that extends [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx) or [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737408.aspx) ([and its possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455018/extending-the-list-of-supported-image-formats-in-gdi))  this way you won't be bound to that 3rd party API.