# How do I add support for a proprietary image format in Windows Photo Viewer / Picasa Viewer

Tags: codec, picasa, image-compression, image-viewer

I am working on developing a lossless compression algorithm using MATLAB.

I would like to see some of my compressed images on windows photo viewer. Could anyone direct me on how to go about doing this? Where may I find specifications to create a codec that would work with windows photo viewer?

I am guessing that I could create a codec as a .ddl file and place it in some windows directory and Photo Viewer could decode my file format. I have seen some softwares from Nikon imaging that, once installed, allowed photo viewer to display the .NEF (Nikon's RAW) files.

I am also willing to consider developing the codec for picasa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending the list of supported image formats in GDI+](http://stackoverflow.com/q/455018/50447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I discovered what I was looking for - It is called [Windows Imaging Component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component).
The [MSDN docs appear to be here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719883.aspx) and an example of an implemented coded is [webP](http://code.google.com/speed/webp/index.html).